# AS3: Hittest cant catch dragged objects in time

Tags: actionscript-3

I use startDrag() to drag object A around and when it hits object B function stops dragging. 
Problem is that if i drag object A too fast into object B it stops dragging while being inside object B. 
Is my hand faster than function that checks collision 48 times per frame?

```
var A:MovieClip;
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dad);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function dad(e:MouseEvent)
{
    A = MovieClip(e.target);
    A.startDrag();
}
function update(e:Event)
{
    if (A !=null && A.hitTestObject(B))
    {
        A.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the MouseEvent.MouseMove event instead of  MouseEvent.EnterFrame.

Also, consider this: Hit test detects if an object collides. It does nothing to separate colliding objects. If your object moves 10 pixels between frames, the objects will test as colliding but could have up to 10 pixels of overlap.
Using stopDrag() will not be sufficient to separate the objects.

Depending on the shape of your overlapping objects, the task of separating them may either be simple, or highly complex. If they are both essentially circular, its pretty easy. If they are both concave polygons, you're in for a world of Math hurt.

Here are some separation methods I have used in the past for simple games.
[Circle-Cirle collision and separation](http://plasticsturgeon.com/2011/03/actionscript-collision-detection-u-circle-circle-collision-detection/)
[Circle-Line collision and Separation](http://plasticsturgeon.com/2011/03/actionscript-collision-detection-2-circle-line-collision-detection/)

(and yes, your hand is faster than that :-) )